# How to deserialize json string in c#?

Tags: c#, json

I have a json string:

```
[{"Id":[1], "Value":"MyText" }, {"Id":[20, 31], "Value":"AnotherText" },{"Id":[2, 3, 4, 5], "Value":"MyText"}]
```

I want to parse it (my json sting already in byte[] array):

```
  private class MyClass
    {
        public int[] Id { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

var stream= new MemoryStream(jsonStr);
var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
var result = (MyClass) ser.ReadObject(stream);
```

But i get exeption:

```
Message "Type 'MyNameSpace.Test+MyClass' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it  
with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want   
serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute.  If the type is a collection,   
consider marking it with the CollectionDataContractAttribute.  
See the Microsoft .NET Framework documentation for other supported types."
```

Whats wrong here?

**Update**

I'd edit my class:

```
  [DataContract]
  private class MyClass
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int[] Id { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

How i not get any exeptions but after deserialize i get object with empty fields.

**Update2**

When i tried parse json string:

```
{"Id":[1], "Value":"MyText" }
```

my code works fine. But how to deserialize a array of objects like this:

```
[{"Id":[1], "Value":"MyText" },{"Id":[2,6], "Value":"MyText2222" },{"Id":[3,4], "Value":"MyText1111" }]
```

Comment: as the error message implies, you should use the correct data annotations

Comment: maybe because its private

Comment: @Cris : I'd check it but using `public` not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**DataContractJsonSerializer** requires that classes must be marked with **DataContract** attribute(and properties with **DataMember**), like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class Person
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Or use JSON.NET libraries, which doesn't require attributes, and has very easy syntax:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
```

Comment: Your'e missing DataContract, DataMember attributes, see my Person class example.

Comment: I've checked and your JSON is invalid, string values must be wrapped with "" marks, "Value":MyText - WRONG, "Value":"MyText" - RIGHT. But it causes other exception than you've posted

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
[DataContract]
private class MyClass
    {

        [DataMember]
        public int[] Id { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```